# Android-studio java : Activity cannot be cast to AdapterInterface in fragment

Tags: java, android

I have an ActivityController that contains a bottom navigation and I want to create interface between RecyclerviewAdapter and Fragment that are inside the bottom navigation to send the adapter position.

## I get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.money, PID: 10644
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.my.money.Content.ControllerActivity cannot be cast to com.my.money.Content.ui.debt.AdapterInterface
        at com.my.money.Content.ui.debt.DebtFragment.onCreateView(DebtFragment.java:52)
```

## DebtFragment :

```
public class DebtFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterInterface {

    private FragmentDebtBinding binding;
    private ClassAdapterDebt adapter;
    private ArrayList<CustomListDebt> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentDebtBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        adapter = new ClassAdapterDebt(arrayList, getActivity(), (AdapterInterface) getActivity());
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        showAllData();

        return view;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClickItem(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

## Interface

```
public interface AdapterInterface {
    void onClickItem(int position);
}
```

## Adapter

```
private ArrayList<CustomListDebt> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private AdapterInterface adapterInterface;

// Constructor
public ClassAdapterDebt(ArrayList<CustomListDebt> arrayList, Context context, AdapterInterface anInterface) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
    this.adapterInterface = anInterface;
}
```

This in onBindViewHolder

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (adapterInterface != null) {
            adapterInterface.onClickItem(position);
        } else {
            adapterInterface.onClickItem(0);
        }
    }
});
```

## My try

I try to change this

```
adapter = new ClassAdapterDebt(arrayList, getActivity(), (AdapterInterface) getActivity());
```

To this :

```
adapter = new ClassAdapterDebt(arrayList, getActivity(), (AdapterInterface) context);
```

Error cannot cast will disappear and replaced with error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.money, PID: 22316
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.my.money.Content.ui.debt.AdapterInterface.onClickItem(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.my.money.Content.ui.debt.ClassAdapterDebt$1.onClick(ClassAdapterDebt.java:68)
```

There are some notes during the build proccess, does this have any effect?

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\asus\AndroidStudioProjects\PencatatKeuangan\app\src\main\java\com\my\money\Content\ui\Adapter\RecyclerHomeAdapter.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Any help will be very important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. To make the interface between the adapter and the fragment in the navHost a little different

## The logic I use

1. First I create an **InterfaceAdapter** between the **adapter and the
   activity_main.java** used as the navHost controller.
2. I sending data from **activity_main.java to fragment** using
   **InterfaceActivity**. The data comes from the InterfaceAdapter.

## InterfaceAdapter

```
public interface AdapterInterface {
    void sendPosition(int position);
}
```

## InterfaceActivity

```
public interface AdapterInterface {
    void sendPosition2(int position);
}
```

## ClassAdapter

```
private ArrayList<CustomList> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private AdapterInterface adapterInterface;


// Edit the contructor
public ClassAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomList> arrayList, AdapterInterface adapterInterface) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.adapterInterface = adapterInterface;
}

// example send position when onClick, do this in onBindViewHolder
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
    adapterInterface.sendPosition(position);
});
```

## MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterInterface {

    private Bundle bundle;
    private InterfaceActivity interfaceActivity;

    // alt+enter and implement method

    @Override
    public void sendPosition(int position) {
        interfaceActivity.sendPosition2(position);
    }

    public void dataHome(InterfaceActivity interfaceActivity) {
        this.interfaceActivity = interfaceActivity;
    }

}
```

## Fragment in navHost

Do this in onCreateView

```
arrayList1.addAll(arrayList);
binding.recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
adapter = new ClassAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList1, (AdapterInterface) getActivity());
binding.recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);

((MainActivity)getActivity()).dataHome(new InterfaceActivity() {
    @Override
    public void sendPosition(int position) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Hope this will help someone